# How can I count the number of lines of the text written in an excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to count the number of lines of the text in an excel cell so I can use this value to make the cell`s height to fit the text.

This is how I am trying to make a merged cell "autofit".

Comment: It depends on what you call the number of lines :) The visible number of lines may not be the actual number of lines. What I mean is that it can be just 1 line wrapped. If your lines are separated by `ALT+Enter` then you can use SPLIT() to find the actual number of lines.

Comment: I would need the visible number of lines =/

Comment: Hmm, that is a tough one then :) Every pc/laptop can have a different resolution and hence it can be slightly complicated to ascertain that and then find the number of lines... But if this `This is how I am trying to make a merged cell "autofit".` is your intention then there is another way to achieve it...

Comment: See [THIS](https://www.google.co.in/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=autofit+merged+cells+vba&oq=autofit+merged+cells+vba&gs_l=hp.3..35i39l2j0l8.2455.8304.0.8754.25.17.0.0.0.0.291.821.1j0j3.4.0....0...1c.1.39.hp..22.3.529.dYnKvZgRlj8) There are many posts which talk about it...

Comment: already found a code to do that =)

Comment: Through the above link? You may want to post a solution so that it may help future visitors. :)

Comment: your link was google haha

i am using this one 

[link]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.misc/tbfik-oQAU4

Comment: Yes it was not just "Google" But links to several post which refers to what you want...